# Why is this JavaScript page redirect so slow?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm implementing a Firefox plugin.  In the plugin's toolbar, I capture the current page and redirect users to the UK Google when they try to go to the Netherlands Google instead.  However, this code takes forever to complete.  When I type "google.nl" or "google.com/nl", my browser shows the Netherlands page and takes at least 1 second before redirecting.

Is there any way to make the redirect faster?  Ideally, I'd like the user to not see the Netherlands Google page at all.

```
function loadURL(url) {
    window._content.document.location = url;
    window.content.focus();
}

var redirected = false;

function onChange()
{

    var url = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.currentURI.spec;
    url = encodeURIComponent(url);

    if(url.indexOf("google.nl") !=-1 || url.indexOf("hl%3Dnl") !=-1){
        if (!redirected){
            redirected = true;
            loadURL("https://www.google.co.uk/");
            return;
        }
    }else{
        redirected = false;
    }
}
```

Note: `onChange()` is triggered by `container.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',onChange, false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First observersation

Never use `DOMSubtreeModified` that's a `MutationEvent` which was supposed to have been removed. You should use `MutationObserver`

So in your case instead of `container.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified, onChange, false);` do this:

```
const gMutationConfig = {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
};

var gMutationFunc = function(ms) {
    for (let m of ms) {
        console.log(m.type, m);
        //if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) { //this test if elements added
        onChange();
    }
};

var gMutationObserver = new this.DOMWindow.MutationObserver(container);
```

### Second thing is

You probably should use `nsIHTTPChannel` for the redirect to be the fastest

```
const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome'); //const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc, results: Cr } = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');

var observers = {
    'http-on-modify-request': {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            console.info('http-on-modify-request: aSubject = ' + aSubject + ' | aTopic = ' + aTopic + ' | aData = ' + aData);
            var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var requestUrl = httpChannel.URI.spec
            if (requestUrl.indexOf('google.com') > -1) {
               //httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED); //this aborts the load
               httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI('data:text,url_blocked', null, null)); //can redirect with this line, if dont want to redirect and just block, then uncomment this line and comment out line above (line 17)
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};
```

#### To start observing

To start start obseving all requests do this (for example on startup of your addon)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

#### To stop observing

Its important to stop observring (make sure to run this at least on shutdown of addon, you dont want to leave the observer registered for memory reasons)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
}
```

Full working example of the observer service to block/redirect urls: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/tree/block-urls

Comment: Works overall!  `redirectTo` wasn't working for me (maybe there was a bug in my code), so I just used `aSubject.cancel` and redirected to my website of choice.

Comment: Cool man, the `redirectTo` function is only avail from ff 22+

Comment: in your github link when i open bootstrap file i cant find where to put the URL that i want to be redirected. lets say i want to block bbc.com and redirect to abc.com ... where do i put the "abc.com" ??

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios right now on line 18 it is redirecting all urls in that array from line 4 and 5 to `data;txt/html,data blocked` so you need to put a a super simple object thing there that figures out based on if abc.com then return whatever url you want to redir to.

Comment: @Noitidart im sorry i didnt got this, im totaly new to javascript api etc. do you want me to make a question of how to do it so you can answer it? thanks!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios no its too easy. here: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/tree/8dcffd8be8e0cd088d55555b3e502900a77e1140

Comment: Ok i think i got it. but i have to put different URLs in `redir_obj` so if i have only google.com in `urls_block` and next in `redir_obj` if i have abc.com... whenever i try to join google.com it should redirect me to abc.com, right?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios with that code it will redirect you to a page saying blocked google. and when go to bbc it will say blocked bbc

Comment: and if i want to redirect me to a whole differen URL?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Then add/change it in the key value pair here: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/blob/8dcffd8be8e0cd088d55555b3e502900a77e1140/bootstrap.js#L9