# Synchronous request when http-on-modify-request fire

Tags: ajax, sdk, firefox-addon, request, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to call an API when the "http-on-modify-request" fire in my firefox addon.

So for now, here is my code :

```
            Request({
              url: "https://myAPI.com/?q="+query,
              onComplete: function (response) {
                var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
                httpChannel.redirectTo(ioService.newURI(response.json.Redirect, null, null));
              }
            }).get();
```

Unfortunately, as it's asynchronous, the first query which fire the observer is already done, so it can't redirect.

Is there another way I can do that ?

Comment: Why not abort the redirecting and then do the redirect? So like `httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);` see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327282/why-is-this-javascript-page-redirect-so-slow/25328750#25328750

Comment: I can't do that because the httpChannel will be canceled, so I can't redirect it later...

Comment: You're right. So abort the channel and then replace it with new channel. That should work. But actually: I thought though that `httpChannel.redirectTo` aborts whatever its doing and then sends it elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you Noitidart, I tried like [that](http://pastebin.com/FE1mb9jC) but it doesn't work either

Comment: Don't do newChannel just to channel.redirectTo like in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327282/why-is-this-javascript-page-redirect-so-slow/25328750#25328750

Answer (score 0):

You should instead fetch a list of redirects periodically from `myAPI.com`, then cache the list locally and use that when "http-on-modify-request" fires.