# Firefox extension: How to intercept the requested url conditionally and block it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my Firefox extension I want to intercept the url that the browser is requesting and block the request entirely if some condition matches

How can I intercept URL being requested?

Comment: I think best option is is nsIContentPolicy but you can also use observer service: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25328750/1828637

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can have a look at the source of those addons

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksite/?src=search
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-n-extension-blockune-bl/?src=search

or use service observer with `nsIHTTPChannel` for fast handling

```
const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome'); //const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc, results: Cr } = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');

var observers = {
    'http-on-modify-request': {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            console.info('http-on-modify-request: aSubject = ' + aSubject + ' | aTopic = ' + aTopic + ' | aData = ' + aData);
            var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var requestUrl = httpChannel.URI.spec
            if (requestUrl.indexOf('google.com') > -1) {
               //httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED); //this aborts the load
               httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI('data:text,url_blocked', null, null)); //can redirect with this line, if dont want to redirect and just block, then uncomment this line and comment out line above (line 17)
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};
```

#### To start observing

To start start obseving all requests do this (for example on startup of your addon)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

#### To stop observing

Its important to stop observring (make sure to run this at least on shutdown of addon, you dont want to leave the observer registered for memory reasons)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
}
```

Full working example of the observer service to block/redirect urls: https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/tree/block-urls

Comment: Thanks, I created a basic addon with `cxf init` and replaced `main.js` with `bootstrap.js` and I get this http://pastebin.com/uZ4bbrsp I am very new to this

Comment: firefox version `38.0.1` and addon-sdk version `1.17`

Comment: best way is to take an existing addon and modify it

Comment: agree, however `cannot find 'package.json' in the current directory or any parent.` fails with this error, so I just created this basic template and added your bootstrap.js to main.js, how to hook these things together, Thank you

Comment: also firefox debugger should be useful to debug your addon to open it (ctrl + shift + j) also you have to enable debugging for addons you could do it easily with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/devprefs/?src=search

Comment: I think I don't understand entry point of the addon, yes I have debugger setup but it never goes to your startup() method where it reigsters all the observers

Comment: here is a simple addon that use nsIHTTPChannel ... download the xpi and extract it

Comment: you did not took an easy stuff to start with on ffox.. good luck but you can pm me as i am working on that for my current addon

Comment: do you happen to have template for chrome as well ?

Answer (score 3):

***An other possible solution :***

Here is an other implementation as modules example from HTTPS-Everywhere

Init function :

```
  init: function() {
    // start observing all http requests
    Services.obs.addObserver(httpNowhere, "http-on-modify-request", false);
  },
```

Observer function :

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
var request = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
  if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
    if (request.URI.spec == "xxx.example.com") {
      request.redirectTo("yyy.example.com");
    }
    else {
      request.cancel(Components.results.NS_ERROR_ABORT);
    }
  }
},
```

***Example addons :***

HTTPS-Nowhere - https://github.com/cwilper/http-nowhere

HTTPS-Everywhere - https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere

***Migrating your extension to chrome :***

i answered your question for chrome in this page :
[Chrome Extension : How to intercept requested urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590428/chrome-extension-how-to-intercept-url-being-requested/30590698#30590698)

Comment: can't accept two answers, please post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590428/chrome-extension-how-to-intercept-url-being-requested