# Chrome extension: how to intercept requested urls?

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, chromium

How can an extension intercept any requested URL to block it if some condition matches? ([similar question for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585385/firefox-extension-intercepting-url-it-is-requesting-and-blocking-conditionally))

What permission needs to be set in manifest.json?

Comment: Please include enough information in this question so that it can be answerable if, say, link goes dead. It's fine and encouraged to link to related questions, but _this_ question should stand on its own.

Comment: @intika Accepted/improved your edit, nominated for reopening.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***JavaScript Code :***

The following example illustrates how to block all requests to [www.evil.com](http://www.evil.com):

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://www.evil.com/") != -1};
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

The following example achieves the same goal in a more efficient way because requests that are not targeted to [www.evil.com](http://www.evil.com) do not need to be passed to the extension:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { 
    return { cancel: true }; 
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

**Registering event listeners:**

To register an event listener for a web request, you use a variation on the usual `addListener()` function. In addition to specifying a callback function, you have to specify a filter argument and you may specify an optional extra info argument.

The three arguments to the web request API's addListener() have the following definitions:

```js
var callback = function(details) {...};
var filter = {...};
var opt_extraInfoSpec = [...];
```

Here's an example of listening for the onBeforeRequest event:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);
```

**Permission needed on manifest.json :**

```js
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "tabs",
  "<all_urls>"
],
```

**Extensions examples and help links:**

- Extension Requestly : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa
- Extension Https-Everywhere : https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere
- Example : https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/blob/master/src/background/background.js
- Wiki : https://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/RedirectionMethods
- Wiki : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: Now that's a much better answer. Thanks for taking time to do this.

Comment: @intika Much appreciated answer. Just improved the formatting.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the request to a different URL?

Comment: Worth noting that the `webRequestBlocking` permission is no longer supported for most extensions using Manifest V3: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/blocking-web-requests. It's been replaced by the Declarative Net Request API