# Block a specific request by it's url in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

how to prevent firefox from making a specific request
to an url, ex: `site.com/ajax/something.php`
i have found a lot of addons but they couldn't really do the job they
can block requests to another domain but not an absolute uri,
Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/facebook-seen-blocker/

Comment: Ad Block lets you block by url in it options or build your own filters https://adblockplus.org/en/filters

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Chrome does this builtin, just select the network request in the networks tab and block it (you have to have developers console open, and "block requests" option turned on for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go man: [firefox extension: intercepting url it is requesting and blocking conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585385/firefox-extension-intercepting-url-it-is-requesting-and-blocking-conditionally/30590432#30590432)

That uses observer service. Ideally you want to use nsIContentPolicy which i think is more performant but i dont have a solution with that to share. The Adblock Plus author is on this forum he may be able to give us a solution i can spam. :P

Answer (score 3):

The solution with addons is to use `AdsBlockPlus`**->**`Filter preferences`**->**`Add filter`, then simply put the url after `||` eg: `||facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php`which will prevent any requests to the url, Programmatically @Noitidart link is a perfect solution i was looking for that too.

Comment: Thanks for sharin! I really want to learn how AdBlock Plus programtically does it, its much more performant then my method I think, because it uses `nsIContentPolicy` I think.